# How can I make a python package (setuptools) and publish in pypi.org?

Tags: python, python-packaging

[In this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67127591/install-python-shout-module-in-windows-10-python-version-3-9/67177448#67177448) i make a py script and an exe file while trying to make a Windows OS python-shout module.

The question now is how can i make a .whl file and publish it to github and pypi.org

The package will only have two files: an exe file, and a .py which will run the exe with Popen and will send and receive data from .exe using stdin and pipe.

Comment: You should be able to find everything here: https://packaging.python.org/ -- If you get blocked somewhere specific then ask a question focused on that specific thing that is blocking you. -- This question as it is right now is not a good question for StackOverflow, it is too broad.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 methods to do so

1. Use twine to upload directly to PyPI

   - Go to PyPI and create an account.
   - Run twine upload dist/* in the terminal/command line.
   - Enter the account credentials you registered for on the actual PyPI.
   - Then, run pip install [package_name] to install your package.   -
2. Use GitHub to upload I have found this article to do using GitHub https://medium.com/@joel.barmettler/how-to-upload-your-python-package-to-pypi-65edc5fe9c56